# Visual studio 2012 overwrites properties in my .csproj project file

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, csproj

I am using Visual Studio 2012. I have many projects each containing at least one .csproj file. The .csproj files contain this section:

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU'">
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    <IntermediateOutputPath>Assembly\Release\</IntermediateOutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <IntermediateOutputPath>Assembly\Debug\</IntermediateOutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x86'">
    <IntermediateOutputPath>Assembly\x86\Debug\</IntermediateOutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x86'">
    <IntermediateOutputPath>Assembly\x86\Release\</IntermediateOutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

For some reason, whenever I open the project in Visual Studio, saving it changes the .csproj file to look like this:

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU'">
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    <IntermediateOutputPath>C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\vs9475.tmp\Release\</IntermediateOutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <IntermediateOutputPath>C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\vs9475.tmp\Debug\</IntermediateOutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x86'">
    <IntermediateOutputPath>C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\vs9475.tmp\x86\Debug\</IntermediateOutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x86'">
    <IntermediateOutputPath>C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\vs9475.tmp\x86\Release\</IntermediateOutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

I have tried several things including adding a BaseIntermediateOutputPath element as well as creating separate conditional IntermediateOutputPath elements. The problem is that this messes with our version control and also generates errors when someone other than myself loads it (because of the local path). Can anyone tell me how to stop visual studio from changing the file every time we load it? This happens to everyone who opens it in Visual Studio 2012. It worked in 2010 but we are transitioning and need to fix this. It is a 2012 project.

Comment: This strongly fits my doctor's usual advice: if it hurts then don't do it.  You are going to have to document your question better to narrow down which VS2012 feature changes this property.  Document the type of project and the add-ins you've got installed.  And try to find a match between you doing something in the IDE and that property changing its value.

Comment: Well that's my problem. I open the solution, erase a semicolon, add it back, click 'save all', and it happens. I have no add-ins. The output type is class library.Also worth mentioning is that it happens in all my projects. I have several hundred of different types.

Comment: I am having exactly the same issue..
It must be some local file overwriting the csproj. In my case some developers are breaking the dependencies for that project whenever they set IIS to local instead IIS Express, for example, but not sure why that change in VS is modifying HintPath values!